# How do I read this stack trace I'm only getting from scrapers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stack-trace

The following is the stack trace error I get when I try to run my site through a validator like http://validator.w3.org/ or the facebook open graph debugger. The thing is, the page appears to load just fine in the browser, or in the mobile app web view. The only way I can see this error is by having the validator show me error pages (option). Any suggestions about how to read the stack trace? I see the reference to one of my controllers `Literrater.Controllers.BookController.Index(Int32 id, String slug)` but I havent changed anything and it used to work, and it works fine in the browser. So, I'm confused. Do I need to check redirect happening or something?

The follow page has the problem. http://literrater.azurewebsites.net/book/33625/birdsong-a-novel-of-love-and-war

```
 [RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type]
  CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) +115
 System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite site, T0 arg0) +661
 Literrater.Controllers.BookController.Index(Int32 id, String slug) +13725
 lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +146
 System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
 System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27

    System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass42.&lt;BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod&gt;b__41() +28
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8`1.&lt;BeginSynchronous&gt;b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass39.&lt;BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__33() +58
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4f.&lt;InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously&gt;b__49() +225
     System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4f.&lt;InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously&gt;b__49() +225
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, your page is not loading and producing the error:

```
Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type

Source Error: 


Line 32:         <div class="status-wrapper">
Line 33:             <h2 class="sub-title">Collections</h2>
Line 34:             @{Model.CollectionVM.FacebookStatus = ViewBag.FacebookStatus;}
Line 35:             @Html.Partial("_MiniBookStatus", Model.CollectionVM)
Line 36:             

Source File: d:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\Book\Index.cshtml    Line: 34
```

It looks like maybe you did not initialize the `ViewBag.FacebookStatus` value in your controller. With those ViewBag values, if you don't set the value in all code paths, then you may have a case like this where the it's `null`.

As an example:

```
protected ActionResult Test()
{
    ViewBag.SomeString = string.Empty;
    ViewBag.SomeBool = false;

    //some code
    if (condition)
    {
        ViewBag.SomeBool = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.SomeString = "Yea I'm a string!";
    }

    return View();
}
```

It's good practice to init the ViewBag values or it can come back to bite you in the Razor view because Intellisense won't pick it up, and it won't cause a build error or warning.

Comment: Turns out I was viewing the page when signed in, which was making it appear that it was loading normally when it was not. Thanks.